# Folder as Variable?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've seen this a lot but I never understood how this works. When I create something with php and GET variables, I always have an url like this:

`https://domain/page.php?variable=something`

How is it possible to use the same script with an url like that:

`https://domain/page/something`

`something` will be the variable then.

But the directory `something` doesn't exist of course and I always get an error 404.

I've tried to get it done with htaccess, I'm almost sure this works somehow, but not exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it in your htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ page.php?variable=$1 [L]
```

Now you can get it on php:

```
$_GET['variable']
```

Comment: If someone have the same problem. The .htaccess should look like:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ page.php?variable=$1 [L]

Comment: You're welcome :), if this helped you, please check as answered.